# Python CGI - End of script output before headers

Tags: python, html, xampp, cgi, response-headers

I've created a simple script that reads an HTML-file and parses some variables on it. Then it creates a new file and writes the HTML-code to it. After that, it should redirect you to the newly created file. But I am getting this error: End of script output before headers.

This is my Python code:

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe

import cgi, urllib.request

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

def varordef(name, default):
   return default if data.get(name) == None else data.get(name)

page_title = varordef('page_title', 'Example CGI')

with urllib.request.urlopen('homepage.thtml') as response:
   html = response.read() % (page_title)
   file = open('homepage.html', 'w')
   file.write(html)

print('Content-type: text/html\n\r') # I've already tried removing this line, but that gives me the same error
                                     # And I also tried putting this line on the top, but then I just get a blank page and it doesn't redirect you
                                     # Also, I tried to put both of those headers on the top, and then it redirects me to the specified URL, but the code below wasn't executed and it didn't create the file, so I get a 404


print('Location: homepage.html\n\r')
```

HTML-file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{0}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=''>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='getfullname.py' method='get'>
        <p id='box-first_name'>
            Please enter your first name:
            <input type='text' id='first_name'>
        </p>
        <p id='box-last_name'>
            Please enter your last name:
            <input type='text' id='last_name'>
        </p>
        <p id='box-full_name'>
            This is your full name:
            <input type='text' id='full_name' disabled>
        </p>
        <p id='box-submit'>
            <input type='submit' id='submit'>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### EDIT:

Here is the Log-file: (fragment)

```
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:   File "Y:/python-web.local/index.py", line 12, in <module>\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:     page_title = varordef('page_title', 'Example CGI')\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:   File "Y:/python-web.local/index.py", line 10, in varordef\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:     return default if data.get(name) == None else data.get(name)\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:   File "C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib\\cgi.py", line 585, in __getattr__\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215:     raise AttributeError(name)\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
[Fri Dec 15 19:31:04.143105 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 7780:tid 1948] [client 127.0.0.1:50913] AH01215: AttributeError: get\r: Y:/python-web.local/index.py
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give more info about the error message, including which line of the code it references regarding the error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing `</html>` tag in your output file.

Comment: What file do you mean? What closing tag?

Comment: Sorry, part of my answer was hidden to due formatting. You're missing the closing /html tag.